# bridging two wireless interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, network-bridge

i am new to linux and i found no answer on google.
my problem is that i want to bridge two wireless interfaces. i already understood that this is not possible with brctl. i have one interface acting as a hotspot and the other one is connected to another wifi network that provides internet connection. now i want to bridge these so that i can log into my hotspot and use the internet connection from the other network my interface is connected to. is there a way to bridge them?

Thank you for all answers

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge does this not work?